# Primefaces datatable selection large dataset slow

Tags: primefaces, datatable, selection, rows

i have a p:datatable with 13000 rows. Scrolling is fast thanks to liveScroll. But if I select all the rows selection becomes slow.
I explain better... I have selection = #{manager.selectedResult}. I fill this variable in server and then every time I select a row is slow... Because client overrides the entire list.. how can I fix it?

Example : In server I fill the selectedResult with 4000 rows.. then if I select another row in client , the client sends to the server a list of 4001 rows that is big and slow

Comment: That is not a surprise its trying to select 13000 rows.  Are you sure that is the best UI paradigm for what you are trying to do?  The Datatable selection is doing exactly what it has to do...I think your use case is outside the bounds of what was intended for that feature.

Comment: Probably the selection feature was not implemented having this case in consideration. I guess every time you click a row on your client the browser will process the whole form and send all the selected rows to the server.. I don't think the client has two lists:  newSelectedItems, unselectedItems to send an optimal subset of items in every process, that would complicate things a little. Have you tried PickList? https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/pickList.xhtml  it could be useful if you need preselected elements.